# SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDB_EXCEL_NOT_SUPPORTED

Tags: sql-server, ssis

When I attempt to run my SSIS package using cmd, I have popup the following error message.
If you have any solutions regarding this, please share them with me.

> [Connection manager “Excel Connection Manager”] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDB_EXCEL_NOT_SUPPORTED: The Excel Connection Manager is not supported in the 64-bit version of SSIS, as no OLE DB provider is available.
> As the error suggests, the Excel Connection Manager does not support the 64-bit version.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr2b8.png)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Did you try searching for the `The Excel Connection Manager is not supported in the 64-bit version of SSIS` error message?

Comment: Run it in 32bit mode or install the 64bit excel driver.

Comment: how to run in 32-bit mode?